# How to create slightly different component based on the same logic and view?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have multiple forms with slightly difference in UI, schema and state but the same logic. I wanted to know what is the bast way to create the forms without duplicate the code. Since there are little differences i thought about creating central place with the common functionality and extend it if needed.
Also, the functionality to render UI elements and set the state accordingly is in class named Form which all the forms inherit from.

I tried to create base factory, then use it to create specific factory but had to instantiate the base factory in order to extend it functionalities.

I tried to create class inheritance chain but had problem with mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps. I also notice that it's not that recommended.

I thought about HOC but i think it's less intuitive in this scenario.

I'm using React 16.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

@ranasulin, and welcome to SO!

The situation you are describing sounds like a good case for [composition over inheritance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wfMtDGfHWpA). React+Redux supports stateless components, functional programming, and doesn't always mesh well with the inheritance pattern (see [the motivations behind Redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/motivation) and [some good examples](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react)). I recommend studying the patterns and anti-patterns of the React+Redux environment, and then reconsider your design with that knowledge in hand.

Good luck!